# 'Inspect element' no longer showing CSS links?

Tags: css

Up until yesterday, I have been able to use 'Inspect element' to show the links to all my Css Stylesheets.

When i clicked on a rule, in the inspection window, I was shown the location of the actual CSS file that was used (ie: http:/mysite.com/template/css/stylesheet.css)

However, since i removed all browsing history and data, I am no longer able to see these links.

Now all i am able to see is the 'generic' site location (ie: index: 6795)

I have tried chrome and firefox and they both show the same... I am unable to show the actual location of the particular CSS files on my server...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Never came across such issue. Can you try to reset settings on your browser and check.

Comment: try opening the file in browser by _right click>open in new tab_

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site? usually when you see the source of the css rule reference index and a line it would imply that the rules have been declared inline.

Comment: Post some screenshots @Sarah, that will help.

Comment: Can you post a url of the website?

Comment: This is a bit of a wild guess, but does your css have a map? This is an option when you're using SASS or LESS, for example (probably with other technologies as well)

Comment: Thankyou for the replies :)...

Comment: Ok,
1) I have reset the settings a few times and tried various settings too, that is why i downloaded another browser and tried it there... same result.

2) when I try to right click and open in a new tab, it takes me to the same website page that i am inspecting.

3) Screenshots... for some reason that function is no longer working, i will try another method and upload those if needed.

Not sure if it does have a CSS map? I am using a Joomla Template. There is a directory file that calls for the 'Less' function, but i have not changed anything there.

Comment: http://www.theboxxedshop.com/img/screen.jpg
![ScreenShot](http://www.theboxxedshop.com/img/screen.jpg)

Comment: Yes! - it does appear as they are now being shown as inline styles instead of the actual css styles and true locations.

Comment: And now... it works? no rhyme nor reason... it would seem that it has now decided that it does want to chow the css style sheets! I would like to be able to say that this is solved, but it isn't really. However, taking a pragmatic approach, I shall crack on while it is easier!

Thanks for your help and suggestions people :)